# Correct way to query in many to many (django)

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to get a list of books that have been added by a favorite by a user. I can pull up a list of all favorites from a user

```
myfavorites = Favorite.objects.filter(user=thisUser)"
```

which will return the correct list of 3 favorites by user1 but then when I try to use that list to get a list of the books with

```
"myBooks" : Book.objects.filter(favorites=myfavorites),
```

I instead only get a single object(the first book the user added to favorites). What is the proper way to query this?

Is the problem in my views or my models?

views.py

```
def books(request):
    if 'userid' not in request.session:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        num = request.session['userid']
        thisUser = User.objects.get(id=num)
        myfavorites = Favorite.objects.filter(user=thisUser)
        context = {
            "user" : thisUser,
            "otherBooks" : Book.objects.exclude(favorites=myfavorites),
            "myBooks" : Book.objects.filter(favorites=myfavorites)          
        }
        return render (request, 'app1/books.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="books")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = BookManager()

class Favorite(models.Model):
    favorite = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="favorites")
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="favorites")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Actually, `models.ForeignKey` is for many-to-one relationships. Also, it is better to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` when writing the relationship destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can do reverse lookup:

```
my_books = Book.objects.filter(favorites__user=thisUser)
```

2 - You can get the favorite book ids first and use them in your `Book` filter:

```
fav_book_ids = Favorite.objects.filter(user=thisUser).values_list("book_id", flat=True)
books = Book.objects.filter(id__in=list(fav_book_ids))
```